# C++11 Problems with GCC 4.8

Tags: c++, netbeans, c++11, cygwin

I have started to experiment with some of the features c++11 has added to the language and I have had problems running a few simple programs.

First of all, let me describe the environment in which I am running these tests and then I will provide a short example.

Because it seemed to be the compiler with the most extensive support for the new standard, i decided to go with GCC 4.8, which I compiled and installed via cygwin (let me also state that my operating system is Windows 8, but I have also experienced the same issues on Windows 7 x64).

I am not compiling by hand, instead I am using Netbeans 7.3.

Example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   std::uniform_real_distribution<double> x { -1.0, 1.0 };
   std::default_random_engine re {};                

   cout << x( re );

   return 0;
}
```

As you can see, in this example I am trying to generate some random doubles, using the most basic generator, right from Stroustrup's site. The compilation goes smoothly, however, when I actually run the resulting executable the following message is displayed in the Netbeans internal console:

```
RUN FAILED (exit value 127, total time: 16ms)
```

Also, when I try to debug the program, using gdb (installed via cygwin) i get the following:

```
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.
```

I can not figure out the cause of this behavior, but I don't think it's some sort of linking problem (I could however be wrong).

I look forward to any suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Your code runs just fine, see http://ideone.com/P3hXzo so I guess it is some sort of problem with your environment.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 12.10 when compiled with g++ 4.8 installed as well.

Comment: Do you get the same results if you compile by hand?

Comment: I have compiled it by hand in the cygwin terminal and it did indeed run. Do you have any idea why the same is not true for Netbeans?

Comment: Well seeing as though when compiling and running by hand it all worked, I can only assume that Netbeans is looking in the wrong place for libstdc++, however there seems to be no option to modify this path from inside Netbeans. But if all is right in the cygwin terminal, shouldn't it be the same for Netbeans, does it not look for the same paths as cygwin?